# Views function not getting triggered

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

Currently, I'm not seeing any errors - but my image isn't being created. This means the views function is not being triggered, as the image generation function works perfectly outside of the views function.

**Views.py**

```
def views_function(request):
print('checkpoint') #This doesn't seem to be getting triggered (can't see the print statement output anywhere)
    def make_image(Na, Fe, Gb, Ty, Fs, Fl):
        #Lots of chart plotting code here
        try:
            fig1 = plt.gcf()
            plt.draw()
            print('saving file')
            fig1.savefig(f'../media/fig{User.profile.chart.url}.png', dpi=100)
        except:
            print('save failed')
        
        return render(request, 'AppName/plot.html', {'title': 'plot'})

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('checkpoint')
        return make_image(100, 1, 16, 1, 1000, 600) and render(request, 'AppName/plot.html', {'title': 'plot'})
```

**HTML button:**

```
<button type="submit" action="{% url 'AppName:views_function' %}" class="btn btn-light" style="width: 515px;">Run</button>
```

**URL Pattern:**

```
path('home/plot/', views.views_function, name='views_function'),
```

**Can anyone see what's wrong? Any ideas are appreciated, I'm getting nowhere right now.**

Comment: You would see it in your console if you are running the server locally with `runserver` cmd. What do you actually see in console when clicking the button?

Comment: Nothing other than the post request @ToniSredanović

Comment: Could you show it? Does it return 404 or what?

Comment: The post request is sent without any problems, output is '[02/Jul/2021 12:17:56] "POST /home/plot/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6564'. That is the only output I get in the console, and the page basically just refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

The print in the first line of the view function views_function don't look properly indented. Try giving a Tab.

Comment: That's my fault, it's not that way in the original code.